# Is there a way to "force" Wix Installer to ALWAYS reinstall specific dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, wix

When installing or updating an application packaged with Wix Installer, is there a way to ignore dependency versions and "force" Wix to **always** install the dependencies at the versions specified by the application being updated?

Context:

I have a .NET application, let's call it `X`, which has dependencies on a class library project, let's call it `Y`. Each has its own separate solution, with different Git repositories. `Y` is distributed via NuGet packages.

We use the Wix Installer to create `X`'s installation package as an .exe and distribute it to users.

We usually release a new version of `X` after rolling out a new version for `Y`.

```
Deploy new version Y -> Update Y's packages in X -> Release X
```

The Problem:

Wix checks the .DLL versions when updating the app, and will only update them in case the "new" versions are numbered higher than the ones currently installed. Since it deletes the "old" ones before updating, it is possible to end up with no .DLL's at all. As a result, users will not be able to start the app.

As an example, let's say we have released `X version 2.5`, which uses `Y version 1.5`. In the event there is an urgent issue caused by `Y version 1.5`, we might need to roll it back to `Y version 1.4` and release an `X version 2.6` that users can use in the meantime until a proper fix is provided via a future `Y version 1.6` (and therefore `X version 2.7`). Some bugs can take a long time to properly address, and many times we cannot afford to wait days for a bugfix.

*Side note: The situation above is purely an example, and the engineering merits of the outlined process is outside the scope of this discussion.*

Thank you for your help!